# Series representation of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x^p)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Consider the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x^p)}{x}dx$ for $p>0$. Assume that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ is the series representation of the integral.

Then, does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ *conditionally converge* for any value of p?

I plan to use find the series representation first. It seems like the Taylor series for $\frac{\sin x}{x}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}$ So
$$\frac{\sin(x^p)}{x}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(x^p)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}$$

I remember hearing that the Taylor series of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ converges for all values. But I want to find out if it conditionally converges *manually*. Can I use the integral test here to test it out? I haven't calculated whether it converges but I have been told that $p>0$ will make the series conditionally converge. Can someone help me with calculating conditional convergence?